# A word for someone who uses their sex appeal to get a job/success in life or who has a job and stays in the job just because of their good looks

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a person who hasn't got any talent or skills for a particular job, say, a reality show, comedy show or a news anchor (no offence).
The person **stays on the job** just because of their good looks which would help increase the number of viewers. Obviously the person was apointed for the good looks (lets keep that appointer off the topic). 
So what would we call this person whose sex appeal is used to run the show. The person is also aware so he/she **is not a victim,** lets just say that.

> She doesn't do anything on the show but flips her hair and throw some of the worst punchlines here and there. She's a --------- (of/on the show). 
>  
>   He used his good looks to charm the lady in a high positon to get his promotion. He's a -------. 
>  
>   She got appointed just flaunting her long legs. She is ------.

Comment: One might say, “She’s ***just a pretty face***.”

Comment: Seductive, seductress, sex symbol

Answer (score 4):

***Eye-candy*** (also *eye candy*) may be what you are looking for.

Collins:

> [**eye candy**  *also* **eye-candy**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/eye-candy)
>   *uncountable noun*
>   Eye candy is used to refer to people or things that are attractive to look at but are not interesting in other ways.
>   [*informal*]
>   Back then, women on TV were mostly seen as eye candy.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary.
>   Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers
>
> **eye candy**
>   *noun* *informal*
>
> **2.**  something intended to be attractive to the eye without being demanding or contributing anything essential
>
> Collins English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers

dictionary.com:

> **[eye candy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/eye--candy)**
>   *noun*
>   **1.**
>   *Slang*. someone or something that is visually attractive or pleasing but is usually considered to lack worth or merit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **window dressing**, i.e. anything used or done only to create a favorable impression. Examples:

> *You want to see her make some decisions and do something,
> she's just window dressing to the other four of us*.
>
> *Flint quits government saying Brown treated her as 'female window dressing*'. ([source](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2009/jun/05/caroline-flint-window-dressing))